# Relationship between rank-$k$ factorizations of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a rank-$k$, $m \times n$-matrix with real coefficients. Suppose that 
$$
A = L_1R_1^T \quad \text{and}  \quad A =L_2 R_2^T, 
$$
where $L_1, L_2$ are $m \times k$ real matrices with orthonormal columns (i.e. $L_1^T L_1 = L_2^TL_2 = I_k$), and hence $R_1, R_2$ are $k \times n$ real matrices.

**Question:** is there a relationship between $L_1$ and $L_2$? are they orthogonal transforms of each other? is it true that $L_2 = L_1 U$ for some $k \times k$-orthogonal $U$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}(X)$ denote the column space of $X$ for any matrix $X$.

Note we must have $\mathcal{C}(X) = \mathcal{C}(L_1) = \mathcal{C}(L_2)$.

Since $L_1$ and $L_2$ have the same column space there exists a $k \times k$ matrix $U$ such that $L_1 = L_2 U$. Since $L_1^T L_1 = I_k$ we have $U^TL_2^TL_2U = I_k$, i.e., $U^TU = I_k$. So $U$ is an orthogonal matrix.